# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMProcessingInstruction::getAttribute(). PHP E DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

Estou a tentar criar um pdf com uma tabela que recebe valores de varíaveis php.

A página corre perfeitamente, mas quando utilizo o DOMPDF para criar o pdf da página ele da-me o seguinte erro :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMProcessingInstruction::getAttribute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\Cellmap.php:554 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\Cellmap.php(518): Dompdf\Cellmap->add_frame(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Inline)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\Cellmap.php(518): Dompdf\Cellmap->add_frame(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\TableRowGroup)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\FrameReflower\Table.php(532): Dompdf\Cellmap->add_frame(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Table)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\FrameReflower\Table.php(408): Dompdf\FrameReflower\Table->get_min_max_width() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator.php(895): Dompdf\FrameReflower\Table->reflow(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Block)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\FrameReflower\Block.php(845): Dompdf\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator->reflow(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Block)) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\FrameDecora in C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\dompdf\src\Cellmap.php on line 554
```

Alguem sabe do que possa ser?

A página é a seguinte :

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../../app/listadeferias.php';





?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="../public/assets/logo.jpeg" style="width: 8%; margin: 0 30px;">

  <h1 style="text-align: center;"> Férias Marcadas </h1>  <table class="table" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom:40px; margin-top: 15px; ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Data Inicial</th>
          <th scope="col">Data Final</th>
          <th scope="col">Numero de dias pedidos</th>
          <th scope="col">Ano referente</th>
          <th scope="col">Dias de férias disponiveis</th>
        </tr> 
        </thead>
         <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {  ?>
         <tr>
         <th scope="col"><?= $value["dferiasinicial"]?></th>
          <th scope="col"><?= $value["dferiasfinal"]?></th>
          <th scope="col"><?= $value["ndias"]?></th>
          <th scope="col"><?= $value["ano"]?></th>
          <th scope="col"><?= $value["feriasrestantes"]?></th>
        </tr>
            <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Dompdf :

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$document = new Dompdf();


$document-> loadHtml(file_get_contents('../public/pages/imprimepgina.php'));



$document->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

$document->render();

$document->stream();

?>
```

Comment: Esse caminho de arquivo realmente existe? O erro parece que ele não consegue carregar esse arquivo. `$document-> loadHtml(file_get_contents('../public/pages/imprimepgina.php'));` Eu digo isso porque eu uso essa biblioteca, A diferença é que montei o html na mesma página e armazenei numa variável.

Comment: Existe, se eu retirar a parte do codigo em que comeca o foreach até este acabar ele cria um pdf com o inicio da tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No meu caso eu fiz uma string e armazenei o html todo dentro dessa string para que funcionasse. Mostrando parte do meu código:

```
 foreach ($produtosTrocaPendente as $item):
                $html .="<tr style='font-size:12px;'>
                      <td class='col-sm-1'><img src='".$dominio.buscaFotoProduto($item['id_produto'])." style='width:100px;'></img>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-md-3'>
                          <div class='form-group'>".$item['referencia']."</div>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-md-5'>
                          <table>";
                          $produtoItemGrade = buscaTrocaPendenteGradeRelatorio($cliente,$item['id_produto']);
                              //tabela de grade de produtos
                              foreach ($produtoItemGrade as $produto_grade):

                              $html .="<td>
                                  <div class='form-group'>
                                      <div><kbd><label>
                                          ".$produto_grade['tamanho']."</label>
                                      </kbd><br>
                                          <b><label>".$produto_grade['pares']."</label></b>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </td>";
                            endforeach;
                          $html .="</table>
                        </td>
                        <td class='col-md-1'>
                            <div class='form-group'>".$item['preco']."</div>
                        </td>
                      <td class='col-md-1'>
                          <div class='form-group'>".$item['pares']."</div>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-md-1'>
                          <div class='form-group'>".$item['valor']."</div>
                      </td>
                </tr>";
            endforeach;
        }
  $html .="</table>
```

No fim para carregar o PDF eu associei a string:

```
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
```

Não sei se soluciona seu problema fazendo assim.

Comment: Sim, tive de alterar algumas coisas mas a ideia foi essa!